# How to load DLL file in PHP

Tags: php, dll

I am developing a custom application in PHP for Mdaemon Mail Server. There are no API samples in PHP, all are in CPP and VB.

I know that we can work with dll in files in PHP using [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) and I am also in windows environment. To get everything started I need to load `MDUser.dll` file.

So far I have downloaded `php_com_dotnet.dll` and have placed it in extensions directory in my wamp server `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext`. I have enabled the extension in php.ini `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll`

This is my code

```
$oMDUser =  new COM("MDUserCOM.MDUser") or die("Unable to instantiate MDUSER COM object");
```

This line throws an error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `MDUserCOM.MDUser' in C:\wamp\www\mdaemon\test.php on line 20
>   ( ! ) com_exception: Failed to create COM object`MDUserCOM.MDUser': Invalid syntax in C:\wamp\www\mdaemon\test.php on line 20

Actually I don't know what MDUserCOM.MDUser refers to. How should I instantiate the COM class. Ex `$obj = new COM("Application.ID")` and what is application and ID in my scenario.

I haven't worked with dll files before. Where I am going wrong and where should I place `MDUser.dll` file. Anyway it is in my working directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was this ever resolved?